Add Dropdown Option on Opening a Grouped Dropdown
When the user opens the dropdown list, I want to add an dropdown item.
This is no problem in an ungrouped dropdown, but when I set [group]="true" this does not seem to work any longer...
I reproduced the issue in a minimal stackblitz here.

There is indeed an apparent issue with the p-dropdown not updating the options when the group option is set to true. A workaround for the situation is adding the following snippet after the unshift happens in the addoption.directive.ts:
      // Reassigning options to satisfty p-dropdown not updating the list when the group option is true
      const options = this.dropdown.options;
      this.dropdown.options = [];
      this.dropdown.options = options;

I suggest you contact PrimeNG and find out why this happens and if it is known/ purposeful behavior.
I hope my answer helped you. Wishing you a wonderful day!

Perfect, that fixed my issue. Gonna file an issue with PrimeNG :)
